# Capture time taken by each pipeline stage in jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I am using a multibranch pipeline in jenkins and would like to record time taken by each pipeline stage and store it in DB. Any ideas on how to get the individual time durations for each build stage? I am just trying to get duration of each stage

Comment: have you tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37009906/access-stage-results-in-workflow-pipeline-plugin

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access Stage results in Workflow/ Pipeline plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37009906/access-stage-results-in-workflow-pipeline-plugin)

Comment: Yes I have tried, but I am looking for just build duration time of each build and then I can upload those durations of each stage to DB

Comment: @userAk I have a similar requirement, did you find a solution ?

Answer (score 9):

The [answer of Patrice M.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64215781/7571258) seems to be the most elegant at first, but there is a problem with *nested* stages and branches. The duration of nested nodes won't be accounted for, instead only the node's own duration will be reported.

Fortunately we can access the [`TimingAction`](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/workflow-api/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/actions/TimingAction.html) of the underlying [`FlowNode`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64215781/7571258) that is wrapped by `FlowNodeWrapper` to calculate the total duration, including nested nodes.

## Solution

1. Find the [`FlowNode`](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/workflow-api/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/graph/FlowNode.html) that represents the start of the branch or stage. Get the start time of this node by querying for its [`TimingAction`](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/workflow-api/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/actions/TimingAction.html).
2. Find the `FlowNode` that represents the end of the branch or stage. Get the start time of this node by querying for its `TimingAction`.
3. Calculate the difference between these two points in time.

Finding the nodes of branches and stages is quite easy using [`PipelineNodeGraphVisitor`](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/blueocean-pipeline-api-impl/io/jenkins/blueocean/rest/impl/pipeline/PipelineNodeGraphVisitor.html) of Blue Ocean plugin API as I have shown in previous answers ([for branches](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64156783/7571258) and [for stages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61837364/7571258)).

For getting the start time of a node, there is a handy static method [`TimingAction.getStartTime(node)`](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/workflow-api/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/actions/TimingAction.html#getStartTime-org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.graph.FlowNode-) which returns the time in milliseconds.

## Example

```groovy
import io.jenkins.blueocean.rest.impl.pipeline.PipelineNodeGraphVisitor
import io.jenkins.blueocean.rest.impl.pipeline.FlowNodeWrapper
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.actions.TimingAction

pipeline {
    agent any
    
    stages {
        stage('A') {
            stages {
                stage('A1') {
                    steps {
                        sleep 1
                    }
                }
                stage('A2') {
                    steps {
                        sleep 1
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    post {
        always {
            printFinishedStageDurations()
        }
    }
}

void printFinishedStageDurations() {

    def visitor = new PipelineNodeGraphVisitor( currentBuild.rawBuild )

    // To find branches instead, replace NodeType.STAGE by NodeType.PARALLEL
    def stages = visitor.pipelineNodes.findAll{ it.type == FlowNodeWrapper.NodeType.STAGE }
    
    for( stage in stages ) {
        if( stage.node.endNode ) {   // only finished stages have endNode
            def startTime  = TimingAction.getStartTime( stage.node )
            def endTime    = TimingAction.getStartTime( stage.node.endNode )
            def duration   = endTime - startTime
        
            echo "Stage $stage.displayName duration: $duration ms" 
        }
    } 
}
```

## Output

[image: Pipeline Blue Ocean view]

### NOTE

When running the above example code in sandbox, you will get errors due to use of "unsafe" Jenkins API. This won't happen when moving `printStageDurations()` into a trusted shared library, as intended.

Comment: Problem is, it asked 13times, to approve scripts.

method groovy.lang.GroovyObject getProperty java.lang.String
method io.jenkins.blueocean.rest.impl.pipeline.FlowNodeWrapper getDisplayName
method io.jenkins.blueocean.rest.impl.pipeline.FlowNodeWrapper getNode
method io.jenkins.blueocean.rest.impl.pipeline.FlowNodeWrapper getType
method io.jenkins.blueocean.rest.impl.pipeline.NodeGraphBuilder getPipelineNodes
method org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.graph.BlockStartNode getEndNode
method org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.steps.build.RunWrapper getRawBuild

Comment: And,
new io.jenkins.blueocean.rest.impl.pipeline.PipelineNodeGraphVisitor
org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun
staticField io.jenkins.blueocean.rest.impl.pipeline.FlowNodeWrapper$NodeType STAGE
staticMethod jenkins.model.Jenkins getInstance
staticMethod org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.actions.TimingAction getStartTime org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.graph.FlowNode

Comment: @Ras Put the code in a shared library, then it won't ask for permission.

Comment: Do not try to do things like this in Pipeline script. Such code belongs in a plugin.

Comment: @JesseGlick I agree that using this directly in a Pipeline script (jenkinsfile) isn't a good idea (and is done in my example for demonstration purposes only). But is there anything that speaks against using such code in a shared library?

Comment: Yes, a library is still Pipeline script, simply versioned somewhere else.

Comment: @JesseGlick This is propably all pretty obvious to you, but could you link to a doc that explains why this is bad practice?

Answer (score 8):

One can use Jenkins workflow API as well to get the data of each stage -

```
https://Jenkins_URL/job/${jobName}/wfapi/runs
```

This will return an array of JSON objects (last 10 runs by default)

This data can then be stored in a time-series DB like InfluxDB.

Answer (score 4):

This has been open for some time, here is a possible answer based on [@adir-d's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59854515/366749)

```groovy
import io.jenkins.blueocean.rest.impl.pipeline.*

def jobName = "folder/project/master"
def run = Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName(jobName).getBuildByNumber(42)

PipelineNodeGraphVisitor visitor = new PipelineNodeGraphVisitor(run)
def stageNodes = visitor.getPipelineNodes().findAll { it.getType() == FlowNodeWrapper.NodeType.STAGE }

for (def node: stageNodes) {
    String stageName = node.getDisplayName()
    println "Result of stage ${node.getDisplayName()} is ${node.status.result} (${node.status.state})"
    println " timings: start=${node.timingInfo.startTimeMillis}ms; durationMillis=${node.timingInfo.totalDurationMillis}ms; paused=${node.timingInfo.pauseDurationMillis}ms"
    println "----------------------------------------------------------------"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Combining answers from "zett42" and "Patrice M." the below can be run in the script console (not relying on `currentBuild`) *and* it shows both stages and nested parallel branches:

```groovy
import io.jenkins.blueocean.rest.impl.pipeline.PipelineNodeGraphVisitor
import io.jenkins.blueocean.rest.impl.pipeline.FlowNodeWrapper
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.actions.TimingAction

def jobName = "MyProject Smoke/PR-7865"
def buildNumber = 4
def workflowRun = Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName(jobName).getBuildByNumber(buildNumber)

PipelineNodeGraphVisitor visitor = new PipelineNodeGraphVisitor(workflowRun)

// Go through all the nodes (you can optionally filter by `FlowNodeWrapper.NodeType` here if you want as per other answers)
for (pNode in visitor.pipelineNodes) {
  if (pNode.node.endNode) {
    def startTime = TimingAction.getStartTime(pNode.node)
    def endTime = TimingAction.getStartTime(pNode.node.endNode)
    def durationSec = (endTime - startTime) / 1000
    float durationMins = durationSec/60.0
    
    println "${pNode.type}: '${pNode.displayName}' took ${durationMins.round(1)} mins" 
  }
}
```

On a job which has 2 stages each of which contain multiple parallel branches, the output looks like this:

```
STAGE: 'linting' took 2.6 mins
PARALLEL: 'hadolint' took 0.2 mins
PARALLEL: 'mypy' took 1.1 mins
PARALLEL: 'pylint' took 2.6 mins
STAGE: 'unit tests' took 4.9 mins
PARALLEL: 'python unit tests' took 4.9 mins
PARALLEL: 'js unit tests' took 3.6 mins
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record since this is unanswered for quite some time, afaik there is no builtin way to achieve this yet (maybe there is some plugin?), however the jenkins pipeline script functionality offers the flexibility to add this yourself, i.e. adding a commands that records a timestamp at the start of a staget and another one at the end of a stage.

I.e. check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40261710/getting-current-timestamp-in-inline-pipeline-script-using-pipeline-plugin-of-hud) regarding getting a timestamp value, you are free to use this for calculations and seding it to some database or other consumer.